# Why can not my http request response parse into an integer?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, httprequest, tryparse

I am making a UnityWebRequest from a php file and get a string as a response (or I think it is a string?).

I am trying to parse the returned response but it keeps returning 0. I will provide all my code and tries, but nothing seems to work, everything returns 0.

Try 1:

```
IEnumerator GetConversationID(int user_id)
{
    WWWForm conn = new WWWForm();
    conn.AddField("cmd", "get_users_conversation_id");
    conn.AddField("userid_php", user_id);

    UnityWebRequest response = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://katiawashere.gr/qr/func/get_user_info.php", conn);

    yield return response.SendWebRequest();

    int.TryParse(response.downloadHandler.text, out StaticHolder.user_convid);

    Debug.Log("This " + response.downloadHandler.text + "," + StaticHolder.user_convid);

}
```

Debug "This 16,0"

Try 2:

```
IEnumerator GetConversationID(int user_id)
{
    WWWForm conn = new WWWForm();
    conn.AddField("cmd", "get_users_conversation_id");
    conn.AddField("userid_php", user_id);

    UnityWebRequest response = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://katiawashere.gr/qr/func/get_user_info.php", conn);

    yield return response.SendWebRequest();

    string m = response.downloadHandler.text;
    int.TryParse(m, out StaticHolder.user_convid);

    Debug.Log("This " + m + "," + StaticHolder.user_convid);

}
```

Debug "This 16,0"

Try 3:

```
IEnumerator GetConversationID(int user_id)
{
    WWWForm conn = new WWWForm();
    conn.AddField("cmd", "get_users_conversation_id");
    conn.AddField("userid_php", user_id);

    UnityWebRequest response = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://katiawashere.gr/qr/func/get_user_info.php", conn);

    yield return response.SendWebRequest();

    int.TryParse(response.downloadHandler.text.ToString(), out StaticHolder.user_convid);

    Debug.Log("This " + response.downloadHandler.text.ToString() + "," + StaticHolder.user_convid);

}
```

Debug "This 16,0"

Try 4?????:

```
IEnumerator GetConversationID(int user_id)
{
    WWWForm conn = new WWWForm();
    conn.AddField("cmd", "get_users_conversation_id");
    conn.AddField("userid_php", user_id);

    UnityWebRequest response = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://katiawashere.gr/qr/func/get_user_info.php", conn);

    yield return response.SendWebRequest();

    int.TryParse("16", out StaticHolder.user_convid);

    Debug.Log("This " + response.downloadHandler.text + "," + StaticHolder.user_convid);

}
```

Debug "This 16,16"

So I think I am going to lose my mind. Why does parsing "16" returns 16 as an int but parsing the response which is also "16" returns 0?? What am I missing here.

Edit:
 If I use the following if statement it never enters, what is the deal?

```
m = response.downloadHandler.text;
n = "16";
if(m.Equals(n))
  Debug.Log("Equals");
Debug.Log(m + "," + n);
```

Debug "16,16"

Comment: Try separating the `yield return` into two lines and adding a `Debug.Log` to the return value of `response.SendWebRequest()`. That might give you some more insight.

Comment: Try setting a string say "t" to response.downloadHandler.text.ToString(), and parsing that.

Comment: nope, still returns 0

Answer (score 0):

I think you have this problem because of different encoding types. C# String is UTF-16 while downloadHandler.text:

> Returns the bytes from data interpreted as a UTF8 string

The question is also how are you creating your response on the server and if data is sent with correct encoding and response type.

You can also compare each character in each string like this: (int) str[0] to check if there are hidden characters or if they have different values.

DownloadHandler.data gives you access to raw bytes which I think is better to use. You can use `BitConverter` to get int from byte array.